# Why is an eigenfunction $\psi_{n,l}$ proportional to $r^{l}$ close to the nucleus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy

This is in reference to *Quantum Physics of Atoms, Molecules, Solids, Nuclei and Particles by Robert Eisberg and Robert Resnick*.

[image: eigenfunction in spherical]

The author writes

**Inspection of the eigenfunctions listed in table 7 - 2 will show that for values of r which are small compared to $\frac{a_{0}}{Z}$ where the exponential term is slowly varying, the radial dependence of all the eigenfunctions has the behavior
$\psi_{n,l}$ $\propto r^{l}$ as the radial distance $r$ is close to $0$.**

Clearly, the eigenfunctions is a function of $\frac{Z}{a_{0}}$. So suppose that $r$ is small compared to $\frac{a_{0}}{Z}$, it must be true that $\frac{Zr}{a_{0}}$ is small and so the decay represented by the exponential term is slow.

Could someone illuminate my doubts by explaining to me with verbosity as to why $\psi \propto r^{l}$ and where the azimuthal quantum number $l$ came to be on $r$?

Comment: This is explained in any decent textbook on the Schrodinger equation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This follows from solving the radial part of the Schrodinger differential equation:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2 \frac{dR}{dr}\right)+ \frac{2m}{\hbar}(Er^2+k e^2 r)R=
\ell(\ell+1)R
\end{align}
If you look at the regime where $r\to 0$ to find an approximate solution near $0$:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2 \frac{dR}{dr}\right)\approx
\ell(\ell+1)R\qquad (r/a_0\ll 0)
\end{align}
you find that indeed $R(r)\sim r^{\ell}$ since
\begin{align}
r^2 \frac{dR}{dr}&=\ell r^{\ell+1}\, \qquad
 \frac{d}{dr}(\ell r^{\ell+1})=\ell(\ell+1) r^{\ell}=\ell(\ell+1)R\, .
\end{align}

Comment: All is clear except for the part where you went to the second expression from the first as $r$ goes to $0$. Why doesn't $r$ going to $0$ kills the term $\frac{d}{df}(r^{2}\frac{dR}{dr})$?

Comment: It may be that $r$ is small, but you cannot know the size of $dR/dr$,  which could be big so that $r^2R’$ is finite.  Indeed, write $R(r)=\chi(r)/r$ to get a slightly different form $r^2\chi’’(r)=\ell(\ell+1)\chi$ with the same solution.